# Bootstrap Modal disappears in android webview but works fine in Browser?

Tags: javascript, android, html, twitter-bootstrap, android-webview

When I open same code in any browser it works perfectly, but in web view all of sudden it disappears, sometimes becomes black.

For your info I've included:

```
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap.js
jquery.js
jquery-mobile.1.4.5.js
jquery-mobile.css
```

Meta Tags:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>            
        <!-- meta character set -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>M-ZAES</title>       
        <!-- Meta Description -->
        <meta name="description" content="Blue One Page Creative HTML5 Template">
        <meta name="keywords" content="one page, single page, onepage, responsive, parallax, creative, business, html5, css3, css3 animation">
        <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Morshed">

        <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is my code and Please tell me why is it happening?

```
     <center>
        <img src="img/zone_switch.png" class="img-responsive zoom-img" style="width:60%" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"/>
    </center>



      <div class="modal fade" data-role="none" id="myModal2" role="dialog" style="margin-top:00px; z-index:30000;">
            <div class="modal-dialog" data-role="none">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content" data-role="none" style="margin-top:50px;">
                <div class="modal-header" data-role="none" style="background-color:lightgrey">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Select Zone</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" data-role="none">


                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" data-role="none" name="optradio" onclick="switchToFirstZone()">First</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" data-role="none" name="optradio" onclick="switchToSecondZone()">Second</label>
                    </div>
         </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: what are the meta tags that has been set on the html

Comment: @AlphaLeader Please give some thoughts

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"> Try with this

Comment: Did it work. Do update.

Comment: @AlphaLeader Nope it didnt work...I moved from modal to overlays for its unexpected behaviour